# Convert nanosecond time to 24 hr format

Tags: react-native

I am getting a time response as 1628165909 format, I want to convert this into 24 hr format for eg: if for 1 AM the response is in nanosecond on front end I want to show it as 1.00 and if it is for 1 PM the response is in nanosecond then I want to show it as 13.00 on front end, please let me know how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```js
let unix_timestamp = 1628165909;
// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
// multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds.
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();

console.log(hours);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).